# Updating an entry slug while viewing the entry on the front-end

Tags: entries, redirect, frontend-form, entry-slug

I'm currently working on an app and functionality as part of the app allows users to edit entries via a front-end form.

As part of editing the entry, users can update the entry title (and the slug gets updated automatically).

When the entry title is changed and saved, obviously the slug will be different, so refreshing the page after the form submit will return a 404 error because it's returning the 'old' page slug.

Any suggestion for a workaround here? What would be the best approach? Ideally after the submit, I love to just return the to same page w/ the updated slug in the url.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across this post & discussion which is exactly what I needed: [How to immediately redirect to an entry after creating the new entry from a frontend form?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35773/how-to-immediately-redirect-to-an-entry-after-creating-the-new-entry-from-a-fron)

Worked like a charm:

```
{{ redirectInput('{uri}') }}
```

Thanks to https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/4169/august-miller for the answer.